# Highstock - why is min/maxPadding on xAxis ignored

Tags: padding, highcharts

Why are min/maxPadding ignored? 
I would like to have padding from both sides on xAxis, that is of type 'datetime'

Check this example out: http://jsfiddle.net/matijash/zs3Ag/

```
$(function() {
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

    chart: {
    },

    xAxis: {
        minPadding: 0.5,
        maxPadding: 0.5
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: usdeur
    }]
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Highstock paddings are not supported,onyl in highcharts.

Comment: Thanks, but why are there min and maxPadding in API then? http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.maxPadding

Comment: Is there any alternative function to be used in highstock to be used as maxPadding ?