# maxPadding on highstocks

Tags: highcharts

I've searched that **maxPadding** is not supported on highstocks (as per this post [Highstock - why is min/maxPadding on xAxis ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734679/highstock-why-is-min-maxpadding-on-xaxis-ignored#answer-20741831)), is there any alternative to it for Highstocks?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not use [ordinal axis](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal), you can expand range programmatically on [xAxis.events.setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/Axis.setExtremes).

```
xAxis: {
  minPadding: 0.1,
  maxPadding: 0.1,
  ordinal: false,
  events: {
    setExtremes: function(e) {
      if (e.trigger) {
        e.preventDefault()
        const navigator = this.chart.xAxis[1]
        let { min, max } = e
        const range = navigator.max - navigator.min

        if (max === navigator.max) max += 0.1 * range
        if (min === navigator.min) min -= 0.1 * range

        this.setExtremes(min, max)
      }
    }
  }
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/qaknvyz9/